# How to move search bar on next line in max width if its mobile screen size on my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, search, layout, bootstrap-4

I have a search bar on my nav bar, but I want it to go on next line in max width if the display is in xs or mobile.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top-sm justify-content-start flex-nowrap bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <a href="/" class="navbar-brand px-2">Top</a>   <!-- brand -->
 <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link px-2 d-none d-sm-block" href="#">Link</a>  <!-- Item 1 -->
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item col-sm-12">
        <a class="nav-link px-2" href="#">Link</a>  <!-- Item 2 -->
    </li>
</ul>


<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input id='urlurl' type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" pattern="https?://.+" required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #0275D8; border-color: #0275D8;" type="button" >Test</button>
            </span>
        </div></div></nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "flex-nowrap" from nav. It should work.
you are using flex box layoout and "flex-nowrap" class doesn't allow wrapping item in next line.